# Unable waiting for web page loading using WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am writing a service with screenshots from the web pages of local sites.
I am using WebBrowser control to capture a webpage as an image.
Below is the code I am using:

```html
namespace MakeScreenShotURL
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Config config = new Config(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            int width = 1700;
            int height = 1700;
            string username = "userdata";
            string password = "passworddata";
            int currentmonth = DateTime.Now.Month;
            int nextmonth = DateTime.Now.Month + 1;
            int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
            screen(width, height, year, nextmonth, currentmonth, username, password);
        }

        static void screen(int width, int height, int year, int nextmonth, int currentmonth, string username, string password)
        {
            string PlaceCode = config.GetAppSetting("place");
            string[] Places = PlaceCode.Split(';'); //contains a list of sites for example: Berlin; Munich; Dresden
            foreach (string pl in Places)  
            {
                using (WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser())
                {
                    browser.Width = width;
                    browser.Height = height;
                    browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = true;
                    Uri uri = new Uri(" http://localsite.php?y=" + year + "&m=" + nextmonth + "&p=" + pl + " ");
                    string additionalHeaderInfo = "Authorization: Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password)) + System.Environment.NewLine;
                    browser.Navigate(uri, null, null, additionalHeaderInfo);
                    Wait(2);  //waiting for pages to load 2 seconds
                    using (Graphics graphics = browser.CreateGraphics())
                    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(browser.Width, browser.Height, graphics))
                    {
                        Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
                        browser.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, bounds);
                        bitmap.Save("C:/Users/user/image/screenshot" + pl + ".jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg); 
                    }
                    Application.Run();
                }
            }
            Application.Exit();
        }
        static void Wait(int number)
        {
            DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
            do
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
            while (time.AddSeconds(number) > DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
}
```

The program creates a screenshot of the first element (Berlin) from the array of Places and saves it to disk.
But when selecting the second element from the array, the program hangs on the execution after the line:

Application.Run ();

Perhaps the program expects something but I cannot understand it.

Can someone help me to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was really intrigued by the fact that this does run at all, seeing that there is no parent window and no user interface for the WebBrowser to interact with.

Anyway, Application.Run() enters the main message loop, thus it waits for messages. This loop usually runs until forcibly stopped, for example by sending a WM_QUIT message.

Application.DoEvents() does a similar thing, but it does not block. It simply looks inside the message queue, executes all messages that are in there, and then returns. So you can remove the call to Application.Run().

If you are creating a serious application, you need to start using at the very least events. Attach a method to WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted and wait there for the page to be loaded, and then run the call to browser.DrawToBitmap.

You'll also need to provide a better way to execute messages than DoEvents, because your current solution will basically hog a single CPU core while the browser is loading.